# Parent Child Forms

Tags: lookup-column

I am running SharePoint Foundation on Windows server 2008.  When the user clicks on a list item, I would like a form to open that has child data on it for the item they selected, much like how it works in SharePoint Designer when you click edit a site page.  How do I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this called [Cascading Lookup](http://www.sharepointboost.com/cascaded-lookup.html), which, by the way, does not support SharePoint 2010 so far. 
In addition to build this tool by your self, you can take a look at Jquery. Lot of people believe JQuery is the best and easiest way to go.

Comment: Thanks John.  

I am new to SharePoint so if anyone can provide a link with detailed information on how this is done, it would be greatly appreceated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Richard,

There is a free plugin called [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation) that will allow you to do this.  This plugin is well documented and very active by it's author.  Definitely worth a look!